# bitcoinjs-lib to Validate Bitcoin wallet addresses in Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, npm

I was wondering how can I use bitcoinjs-lib to validate bitcoin wallet addresses in Vanilla Javascript.

I have got this working in node.js but I want to do it the other way, i mean for vanilla javascript.
Below is code.

```
var address = document.form.input.value.trim();
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
bitcoin.address.toOutputScript(address ,bitcoin.networks.bitcoin);
```

Comment: Yes you can. RTM https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib

Comment: @mplungjan Do you mind explaining what RTM is?

Comment: Read The Manual

Comment: Well, the manual says the recommended method to use the lib in the browser is through Browserify. It doesn't say anything about vanilla js.